# Determine the Bayes estimator of $\theta^2$ under the conjugate prior for the normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

Consider the following model: $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid $N(\theta,1)$ and $\theta \sim N(0, \tau^2)$ for some known $\tau^2$. Determine the Bayes estimator of $\theta^2$ under the squared error loss.

I know the posterior distribution of $\theta$ given the observed sample $X_1,...,X_n$ is $N(\frac{\tau^2}{\frac 1n + \tau^2} \bar{X}, (\frac{1}{\tau^2} +n)^{-1})$.

So if the question asks me the Bayes estimator of $\theta$ under the squared error loss, I know that is $\frac{\tau^2}{\frac 1n + \tau^2} \bar{X}$. But now the question is about  the Bayes estimator of $\theta^2$ .

Comment: Have you tried using the König-Huygens formula?

Comment: Bayes estimator of any function $g(\theta)$ under squared error loss is similarly the posterior mean of $g(\theta)$ given the sample.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so the Bayes estimator of $\theta^2$ is the expectation of $\theta^2$ under the posterior distribution of $\theta$?

Comment: Prove it. Don't take my word for it.